# Moving USB hard drive Windows 11 storage space pool to a Windows 10 PC

Tags: storage-spaces

I recently tried successfully to set up a parity storage space pool made up of 3 8TB USB drives. I transferred a lot of data to the drives, and the system works well. I know how to check the health of both the physical drives and the pool, and all looks good.

But having worked with computers since the 1980s, I know all computers fail eventually. When that happens, I haven't found the methodology of moving the pool to a new PC. Plenty of sources say to copy all data to an intermediary media and copy that to a new set of drives attached to the new PC, but not much about setting it up if the old PC dies.

Do I just hook up the 3 drives and they just work with no data loss, or is there a procedure for alerting the new PC to handle the 3 drives as a pool?

Comment: On the Windows 11 PC, after taking the pool offline, I physically disconnected the discs, verified that they were gone in Settings and File Explorer, then reconnected them and the pool came back successfully.

Next I took the pool offline again and connected them to a Windows 10 PC (updates current). Although the drives were recognized as existing, the file system was marked unidentifiable, so the pool wasn't mounted or recognized. I'm not sure where to go from here. The whole pool concept is pretty worthless if they can't be moved from one PC to another.